# how to make my method wait untill promise completes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, promise

I have a method (in play framework) from which i will call i will call a webservice but in play 2.4.0M2 version the response i am getting is wrapped in a promise.

So the method return back to do it's normal work without waiting for the webservice to complete.That makes some issues to mu previous flow.So now i have to make the method wait on same line where i am calling the webservice and continue to execute from next line once the webservice returns some response.

Is there any way to do it.

**My code:**

```
Promise<WSResponse> response = WS.url(SignConstants.SIGN_DOCUMENT_URL).post(new File(inputfilepath));

return response.map(new Function<WSResponse, Boolean>() {
   public Boolean apply(WSResponse response) throws Exception {
      //some code here 
      return Boolean.TRUE;
  }
});
```

Comment: This code looks just fine - where is the code with the problem waiting for it?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum as it was returning promise<Result> my next line of codes will be executed before web service returns anything.Anyway i got the answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer for it by myself.

It's all about using the get method specifying the timeout as parameter.

**Answer:**

```
WSResponse response=WS.url(SignConstants.SIGN_DOCUMENT_URL)
.post(new File(inputfilepath)).get(10000);
```

in which my result is not wrapped with promise so i will get my desired output.

Anyway Thank you every one..

Answer (score 0):

where are you calling this method from? inside a controller method that services a request? if yes you should return a

```
Promise<Result>
```

instead of plain `Result`. Refer to the section Async results in the doc https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync

Comment: it's k in play 2.2 i am asking about play 2.4.0M2 version.anyway i got my answer.